# Remove the highlight from combobox in readonly mode (python)

Tags: python, combobox, highlight, readonly

I would like to remove the highlighting from my combobox widget when the user selects an option. But the method select_clear() doesn't seem to be working :(

Any clues why ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

class hey(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        self.comboboxVariable = StringVar()
        values = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

        self.comboBox = Combobox(self, textvariable = self.comboboxVariable, values = values, state = 'readonly')
        self.comboBox.pack()

        self.comboBox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.updateData)

    def updateData(self, event =None):

        self.comboBox.select_clear()


myClass = hey()
myClass.pack()
root = myClass.master
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: possibly `self.comboBox.select_clear()` should be [self.comboBox.select***ion***_clear()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.selection_clear-method) ?

Comment: Nah it's not working neither.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do and what your script is attempting to do are two different things. First, you have event = None, which causes the function to be called when you first initialize an object and then never again. Instead, leave the function attribute just as 'event' so that it runs when the specified event takes place.

To remove the selection made, your updateData function would look like the following:

```
def updateData(self, event):

    self.comboBox.set("")
```

However, to remove the highlighting from the chosen value, you would need to change the focus from the combobox to the root window:

```
def updateData(self, event):

    self.focus_set()
```

Hope this helps.